# How to get all the tables on which a particular user has access-DB2

Tags: sql, db2, database-schema

I need to know all the tables on which particular user let's say 'Abc' has any(read, write) kind of access.

Is this possible in db2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES` administrative view. You can find more about it in the [DB2 Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0021978.html):

`SELECT AUTHID, PRIVILEGE, OBJECTNAME, OBJECTSCHEMA
   FROM SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES WHERE OBJECTTYPE='TABLE' AND AUTHID='userID'`

Comment: That view is good, although it only shows privileges granted directly. It is more difficult to also show privileges that a user might have inherited from a `ROLE` or `GROUP` or from some authorities the user might have (or inherit). If you need indirect privileges as well, probably best to ask a new SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below to get list of of users, corresponding table and type of access(delete, modify, update, select etc),

SELECT  GRANTEE,TTNAME ,GRANTOR ,  DATEGRANTED ,GRANTEETYPE , SELECTAUTH ,ALTERAUTH , DELETEAUTH , INDEXAUTH , INSERTAUTH ,DBNAME , SCREATOR , STNAME ,
    TCREATOR ,  AUTHHOWGOT , TIMESTAMP ,  TIMEGRANTED
    , UPDATECOLS ,
     UPDATEAUTH , IBMREQD , GRANTEELOCATION , LOCATION ,
    "COLLID" , CONTOKEN , CAPTUREAUTH , REFERENCESAUTH , REFCOLS ,
    GRANTEDTS , TRIGGERAUTH , GRANTORTYPE
FROM "SYSIBM".SYSTABAUTH
WHERE ( GRANTOR like '%'
    AND GRANTEE like '%' ) ;