# Get a list of all tables I have access to without poking each of them manually?

Tags: sql, db2

My company uses db2 and I see tons of schemas/tables on our server. To most of them I have no access, i.e. it gives me:

> An error occurred while performing the operation:
>   The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation. Authorization ID: "____". Operation: "SELECT". Object: "_____".. SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, DRIVER=4.22.29

Is there a way to get a list of all tables I have access to without poking each of them manually?

My attempt:

I have found the following similar question: [How to get all the tables on which a particular user has access-DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602513/how-to-get-all-the-tables-on-which-a-particular-user-has-access-db2)
. However, I obviously don't have access to this `SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES` administrative view.

Comment: On DB2 ZOS the table grants are stored in `SYSIBM.SYSTABAUTH`

Comment: @Stavr00: Thanks! One problem with `SYSIBM.SYSTABAUTH`: many tables have `SELECTAUTH = G` and I can select from them. Many also have `SELECTAUTH = G` but I can't select from them. Is there a way to list only those I can select from?

Comment: @Stavr00: Moreover, tons of tables have `SELECTAUTH = Y` but I can't select from them.

Comment: What operating-system runs your Db2-server (z/os, iSeries, Linux/Unix/Windows) ? Does the site implement database roles or external security?

Comment: @r_a Please see the description of the columns in `SYSCAT.TABAUTH`.  You have to look at `GRANTEE`, `GRANTEETYPE`, and `SELECTAUTH` to figure out if you can select from any given table.